# Jenkins: Batch command returns negative value when we expect 0

Tags: jenkins, googletest

Jenkins: Batch command returns negative value when we expect 0.

Jenkins Version - 2.249.1
After executing windows batch command - google test for the c++. All the tests were passed with few disabled tests. We are expecting a value 0, but received negative value. (-1073741819 ).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXZKk.png)
-1073741819

What is the issue here? Why are we getting a negative value?
This is leading to build failure.

Comment: There is no convention for what non-zero return codes a batch file uses to report errors or even if it returns non-zero upon error! You need to read the batch script and see what it is doing.

Comment: Could it be that you tear down fails? We have that sometimes when a thread was left running from one of the unit tests, it didn't get logged properly but the unit test executable crashed on exit.